# Why have the direct links between META and TeX.SE gone?

Tags: discussion, design

You used to be able to just click on a direct link to step from META to TeX.SE or vice versa. This is gone from the latest interface upgrade. Was there a good reason for this?

Comment: you're not the only person to have this question.  it was also raised [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4008/579)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for telling me. Your title is very general. When I originally searched for mention of this problem I couldn't find it.

Comment: You can click on “meta” in the Community Bulletion in the right column, which will open meta in a new window. I don’t think there’s a comparable way back to the main site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) as it's a feature of the new top bar. The link is in the 'StackExchange' menu (top-left of screen), where the link for the meta site is directly underneath that for the main site. The same applies to every other StackExchange network site in the menu.

Comment: How did I not realise that? No prizes for answering that question.

Comment: @GeoffPointer Well it's not universally popular, so I wouldn't say that the design decision is necessary correct, just that it is deliberate!